# values and values-normal folder in android

Tags: android, directory

I have created the following folders:

```
values

values-small

values-normal

values-large
```

In each folder I have putted my resource file: dimen.xml file.

My question is: **what is the difference between values and values-normal folders?**

For example, in `values` I have a dimension set for mdpi (30 dp) resource. What value should I put in `values-normal` ?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing.  Android works via overrides.  So it will initially grab everything in the values folder, then override with anything in the -xxx folders of the appropriate type.  If you don't want to override a value you don't have to.  However android gives you the flexibility to override on normal but not large or small if you really want it.